# Repeating regex groups

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to get some information from a web site. The information I want is in a table so I made a regex but I don't know the right way to simplify it.

The following are two parts of my regex that I would like to simplify:

```
<br>(.*)<br>(.*)<br>(.*)

<tr><td>(.+)r>(.+)r>(.+)r>(.+).+</td></tr> # This part should be repeated n times(n = 1 to 10)
```

I looked through the python documentation and I can't realize how to do it. Perhaps you can give me a hint.

Thank you,
mF.

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML! Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wrong way to go unless you're trying to scrape some data out of a tiny fragment.

It would be much better if you used a tolerant HTML. BeautifulSoup mentioned earlier is a good one but it's stagnating and I don't believe it's being maintained actively anymore.

A highly recommended parser for Python is [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/).

There was a long thread discussing parsing XHTML on one of our local mailing lists [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/bangpypers@python.org/msg02074.html) which you might find useful too.

Answer (score 3):

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

"Have you tried using an XML parser instead?"

EDIT: This is the way to go: [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the block in parens and then use the {...} operators, e.g.:

```
(foo...){1,10}
```

Matches 1 to 10 instances of the thing inside of there. Given your example above, you can nest those:

```
((f..)(b..)){1,10}
```